# Python Input function - number and string

Tags: python, input

I am trying to get python to do the following

```
while tries:
   guess = input ("Guess no: " + 3-tries+ ": ")
   ....
   tries=tries-1
```

but I get the error message `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`. 
How can I successfully code this?

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* cast variable of type `int` to `string` implicitly. You have to use `str()` method.

**For example:**

```
>>> str(10)
'10'
```

So, you have to write:

```
input ("Guess no: " + str(3-tries) + ": ")
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)

Comment: @jsmith613 if that worked for you, please, consider marking my answer as `Correct` (:

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's string formatting to print an `int` in a `string`

```
guess = input ("Guess no: {}: ".format(3-tries))
```

Or, for python2.6

```
guess = input ("Guess no: {0}: ".format(3-tries))
```

Comment: Use `input("Guess no: {0}".format(3-tries))` so that python2.6 would be happy, right?

Comment: yes, python 2.6 needs an index, python >2.7 doesn't require that